# Visa for Thai wife going on holiday with British husband in Spain

Tags: visas, uk, spain, thai-citizens

I am a British citizen with a Thai wife, who at the moment is in the UK on a settlement visa. I am looking at taking a holiday with her to Spain in early 2018, 2-3 weeks.

Would my wife need at visa to visit Spain and if so what visa does she need?

If she does need a visa do you have an idea of what the cost would be?

And are there certain criteria that need to be met? She works part time and I'm in full time employment.

Comment: @JonathanReez the title was fine.  The title you've created changes the question considerably, because the person asking the question doesn't need any visa at all.

Comment: @phoog yes but his wife does

Comment: @JonathanReez your title does not ask about his wife.

Answer (score 1):

From the [web pages of the Spanish embassy in London](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/Visas.aspx), you can learn that your wife needs a visa.

They're not so forthcoming about the fact that the visa should be free of charge under the European Union's [freedom of movement rules](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).

Under those rules, the only criteria that need to be met are that you are an EU citizen, that she is married to you, and that you will travel together.

Comment: *They're not so forthcoming about the fact that the visa should be free of charge under the European Union's freedom of movement rules.* From the page you linked: "There will be no charge for the spouse and/or dependants of an EU citizen".

Comment: I would also note that if the asker wishes to obtain a visa without paying, they should apply directly to the consulate, by letter, rather than going via BLS international, who will charge £12.80 for an EU/EEA spouse visa. This information is contained within the page you linked and this page. https://uk.blsspainvisa.com/london/eea_eu_type_visa.php